# Mark a mailitem as sent (VBA outlook)

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have problem with change the sent property of mail, because the property is read-only and I need to change it from the level of vba.

The problem appears after sent the mail from a shared mailbox (using online outlook mode). The mail doesn't go to folder "sent items" in shared mailbox but stay in outbox folder. I have made macro to move the mail to correct folder and everything is fine but the mail have status unsent (when you open the mailitem you are in editing mode). I can't find any solution for the problem.

This is the outbox folder with correctly sent mail and mail sent from shared mailbox:

[image: image screenshot]

Comment: Can you verfy, the mail is **really** sent?

Comment: Yes, every email sent from shared mailbox was delivered.

Comment: It seems [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/outlook-email-stays-outbox) describes your problem. There is no possibility to achieve your goal with vba obviously

Comment: Ok, when I press the button "Send/Receive" the mail change the status, so it's helpful ;) remember that I'm writing about problem with outlook in online mode (not exchange mode). As I said before the mail is deliver but somehow in outbox folder stays as unsent.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with not very tidy way. I changed the registry key DelegateSentItemsStyle to 0 and when I did it, the sent mails went to my personal sent Items folder.  Then I just move the mails to shared mailbox.