# I want to customise following part in my outlook plugin through c#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

[image]

I want to make a button of send password of my encrypted mail in the red highlighted portion. Please guide me some thing how can I achieve this in my outlook plugin.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Questions showing little to no effort generally get downvoted and closed.

Comment: yes i hv executed my plugin it is wrking till send mail and mails are then moved to email cipher folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That area cannot be customized. The best you can do is set a category - it will be shown there.

Comment: Thanks For your Answer but the problem i am facing is i m sending email through my api web services and movinf that email to this folder now i want to achieve is these emails shown here should appear as sent email items and not as draft email please help me figure out you can reach me at sonikasood94@gmail.com

Comment: So the question is how to create messages in the sent state? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137942/mark-a-mailitem-as-sent-vba-outlook

Comment: I cant find any code to create a Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olPostItem);Please share me a link that can help me to create a olpostitem in outlook Thank you

Comment: var msgdata  = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olPostItem);
                                       
                                  msgdata.Body = mail.Body;
                                  msgdata.Subject = mail.Subject;
                               
                               
                                  msgdata.MessageClass = "IPM.Note";
                                  msgdata.Move(folder); i have used this it helped me too achieve my thing quite a lot but how can i copy all the attachments

Comment: Copy attachments from where? Are you not creating a brand new item?

Comment: void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel){
 Outlook.MailItem mail = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
 var msgdata  = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olPostItem);
//  msgdata.Attachments = mail.Attachments;  
  }
//this mail item is the mail item i am sending using my own webservices and i want to copy the same mail in this msgdata and also change its class msgdata.MessageClass = "IPM.Note";

Comment: For all attachments in the source email, call Attachment.SaveAsFile, then add the attachments to the traget email using Attachments.Add

Comment: Thanks please help me figure out this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742983/outlook-addin-shows-inactive-at-load-only-in-outlook-2016